# Will a gerund form of "hope" be acceptable if followed by an infinitive?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds

> I am **hoping to make** Scotland my permanent home.

Is it correct to use ‘hoping to make' in this way?

Comment: Read about the grammar tenses, especially the present continuous tense.

Comment: What's the problem with the construction be + hoping to do? Did you look up the verb _hope_ in a dictionary?

Comment: The example from [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hope_1) : Joan's hoping to study law at Harvard. BTW I am not hoping for your thanksgiving in favour of me. Take it for granted.

Comment: *Hope* and *am hoping* are both acceptable, although in writing *hoping* occurs far less frequently than the simple present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very common construction, and perfectly acceptable in everyday English.

A slightly more formal sounding way of expressing it would be:

> I hope to make Scotland my permanent home.